# How to print an array that it looks like a hash

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl, and have to write a code which takes contents of a file into and array and print the output that it looks like a **hash.**  Here is an example entry:

```
my %amino_acids = (F => ["Phenylalanine", "Phe", ["TTT", "TTC"]])
```

Out put should be exactly in above format.

Lines of Files are like this...

```
"Methionine":"Met":"M":"AUG":"ATG"
"Phenylalanine":"Phe":"F":"UUU, UUC":"TTT, TTC"
"Proline":"Pro":"P":"CCU, CCC, CCA, CCG":"CCT, CCC, CCA, CCG"
```

I have to take last codons after semicolon and ignore the first group.

Comment: So, are we to assume that the 3rd string in the colon-delimited list is to be the hash key? Also, more details on the desired output would be helpful. Your "example entry" isn't valid code...

Answer (score 3):

Is it your intention to build the equivalent hash? Or do you *really* want the string format? This program uses [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) to build the hash from the file and then dumps it using [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDump) so that you have the string format as well.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dump 'dump';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ':' });
open my $fh, '<', 'amino.txt' or die $!;

my %amino_acids;
while (my $data= $csv->getline($fh)) {
  $amino_acids{$data->[2]} = [
    $data->[0],
    $data->[1],
    [ $data->[4] =~ /[A-Z]+/g ]
  ];
}

print '$amino_acids = ', dump \%amino_acids;
```

**output**

```
$amino_acids = {
  F => ["Phenylalanine", "Phe", ["TTT", "TTC"]],
  M => ["Methionine", "Met", ["ATG"]],
  P => ["Proline", "Pro", ["CCT", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"]],
}
```

**Update**

If you *really* don't want to install modules (it is a very straightforward process and makes the code much more concise and reliable) then this does what you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'amino.txt' or die $!;

print "my %amino_acids = (\n";

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my @data = /[^:"]+/g;
  my @codons = $data[4] =~ /[A-Z]+/g;
  printf qq{  %s => ["%s", "%s", [%s]],\n},
      @data[2,0,1],
      join ', ', map qq{"$_"}, @codons;
}

print ")\n";
```

**output**

```
my %amino_acids = (
  M => ["Methionine", "Met", ["ATG"]],
  F => ["Phenylalanine", "Phe", ["TTT", "TTC"]],
  P => ["Proline", "Pro", ["CCT", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"]],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually want valid perl as the output, this will do it:

```
open(my $IN, "<input.txt") or die $!;

while(<$IN>){
    chomp;
    my @tmp = split(':',$_);
    if(@tmp != 5){
        # error on this line
        next;
    }
    my $group = join('","',split(/,\s*/,$tmp[4]));
    print "\$amino_acids{$tmp[2]} = [$tmp[0],$tmp[1],[$group]];\n";
}
close $IN;
```

Using your sample lines, the output is:

```
$amino_acids{"M"} = ["Methionine","Met",["ATG"]];
$amino_acids{"F"} = ["Phenylalanine","Phe",["TTT","TTC"]];
$amino_acids{"P"} = ["Proline","Pro",["CCT","CCC","CCA","CCG"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

@Borodin Thank you very much for your answer, actually I don't have to use Text::csv or Data::dump.I  have to open a file and build the equivalent hash from the file.I am trying to do without using both, hopefully it will help.Thanks again!!!

Answer (score -1):

Perl has no special method to print hashes.  What you should probably do is create a hash when reading the file:

```
while (<FILE>) {
    my @line = split ':'; # split the line into an array
    $amino_acids{$line[0]} = \@line[1..-1]; # take elements 1..end 
}
```

And then print out the hash one entry at a time:

```
foreach (keys %amino_acids) {
    print "$_ => [", (join ",", @$amino_acids{$_}), "]\n";
}
```

Note that I didn't compile this, so it may need a small amount of work to get it done.