# Please explain meaning of perl code

Tags: perl

What exactly this code is doing, what is the meaning of s* in perl, is there any other way to write this code.

```
my $group = join('","', split(/,\s*/, $tmp[4]))
```

Comment: This is not even the complete line. Can you at least complete it?

Comment: Rohit to explain meaning of s* in regular expression you don't need full line...my $group = join('","',split(/,\s*/,$genetic_codes[4]));Any ways this is the full line....

Comment: Yeah true. But you should always post compilable code on SO.  That is why I asked you to complete it.

Comment: Its OK no problem...I will be careful next time,thanks for responding.

Answer (score 7):

`,\s*` is a [regular expression pattern](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) that matches strings starting with a comma (`,`) followed by zero or more (`*`) space characters (`\s`).

[`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) uses this pattern to determine what to consider a separator on which it should split. For example, with that pattern, it will split the string `foo,bar, baz` into the three strings `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

The following are what Perl 5.14.2 and Unicode 6.0.0 consider space characters:

- U+00009 CHARACTER TABULATION
- U+0000A LINE FEED (LF)
- U+0000C FORM FEED (FF)
- U+0000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)
- U+00020 SPACE
- U+00085 NEXT LINE (NEL)
- U+000A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
- U+01680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
- U+0180E MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
- U+02000 EN QUAD
- U+02001 EM QUAD
- U+02002 EN SPACE
- U+02003 EM SPACE
- U+02004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
- U+02005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
- U+02006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
- U+02007 FIGURE SPACE
- U+02008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
- U+02009 THIN SPACE
- U+0200A HAIR SPACE
- U+02028 LINE SEPARATOR
- U+02029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
- U+0202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
- U+0205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
- U+03000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE

Comment: Updated my answer to include an explanation of the role of the pattern about which you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your code when compilable looks like:

```
my $test = "abc, xyz, mno";
print join('","', split(/,\s*/, $test));
```

It can be re-written as:

```
my $test = "abc, xyz, mno";  
my @tokens = split /,\s*/, $test;   # split $test on `,\s*`
print join '","', @tokens;          # Join the array back on `","`.
```

And what that `regex` means is already been explained by @ikegami in his answer.

Remember that, you can `omit` the parenthesis where it does not change the meaning in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

That is part of this line from an answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918936)

```
my $group = join('","',split(/,\s*/,$tmp[4]))
```

I think it is better written as

```
my $group = join ', ', map qq{"$_"}, $tmp[4] =~ /[^\s,]/g;
```

The regular expression pulls out all the groups of characters that aren't whitespace or a comma, so when applied to the string `TTT, TTC` the result is `TTT` and `TTC`. The `map` puts double quotes around each item. And the `join` joins them all into a single string, separated by `,`. This gives `"TTT", "TTC"`

Did you read my answers to your previous two questions? The only problem seemed to be that you didn't want to install a module, and I have written an alternative for that case.

Comment: Why is this better than the split solution. Seems more complicated to me.

Comment: @justintime: It's a matter of taste, but I think it's clearer to wrap each element in quotes and then separate them with commas than to separate them with quote, comma, quote.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rohl Jain.  it is a code fragment. I came up with case.

```
my $line = 'a,b, c,  d,e';
my $newline = '"'.join('","',split(/,\s*/,$line)).'"';
print $newline;
```

This is the output.
"a","b","c","d","e"

It takes a line of data that is comma delimited, removes space padding, and creates a line that is comma delimited and double quote encapsulated. Note I added a double quote at the beginning and end of the line.